# Battery usage got very high after switching to Ubuntu (HP Pavilion G6-2348SG)

Tags: drivers, hp, battery

I just switched to Ubuntu from Windows 7 on my HP Pavilion G6-2348SG Notebook and it seems like the battery usage increased a lot. 
Also, I cant find any drivers, which would probably solve the problem.. I hope you guys can help me.

Edit: I have a Radeon HD 7670M graphics card

Comment: Obviously it's your graphics driver which is not installed. Some can suggest you to install graphics driver if you'll provide the graphics card info in your laptop. If you don't know how to get then this command will help you: `sudo lspci | grep VGA`. Edit your question and post the output of this command.

Comment: And with an AMD, don't even bother looking for a driver, AMD doesn't care(last time I have an AMD in something ever).

Comment: You have to install [AMD Catalyst Proprietary Driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx). Just go to the link and download and install it. Here is the [installation instructions](http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/catalyst_linux_installer.pdf) Hope it'll help you..

Answer (score 0):

You should consider installing jupiter

You can select power modes with it, and it's very easy to control. It really saves out battery.

Open terminal and do this.

Add the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
```

Update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install jupiter

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

And to other people reading this and are using an Asus EEPC netbook, install this asswell

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee
```

Have a nice day :)